# Lost GUI suddenly on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, gui

Running a clean machine, purchased from System76 in mid May 2014, with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed.

Being an ex Windows user I am used to spending a lot of time keeping my machine tight.  I clean and update like crazy, and I brought that habit to my new Linux machine as I want things to stay good.  So, every morning I run six update commands: dist-upgrade, upgrade, update, autoremove, autoclean, & check, and then I run them all again (because I've noticed things are sometimes different the second time around).  I have aliased these so I only type one letter (u) and my password, and those six commands run, twice.  Also, once a week I use bleach bit in both regular and super user modes, and I haven't checked all those boxes, just what I think are the safe ones.  I have been doing this for a while now and everything has been good.  I have even run these commands since I lost my GUI and I get no error messages.  Everything seems to be well.

I have only downloaded a small number of things not from the software center: Google Earth, Google Chrome, and a couple of other small things that I forget what they are but those were quite a while ago and have given me no problems that I can detect.

I work hard to keep this box in a good clean condition.

So, this last Saturday morning (February 28) I fire my baby up and I got no GUI.  What?  The rest of the machine works.  I'm writing this in one of those other shells (CTRL ALT F1).

I have looked over a number of the other questions found by searching for "Lost GUI Ubuntu 14.04" and they all seem to be for other circumstances, speciality cases, unless of course I missed something.  In my case, I had it fresh from the factory, all has worked well for well over six months and then, all of a sudden, poof!  It's gone!

So, I don't know what to think really.  I don't think any of my hardware died.  I wouldn't think any of those updating commands or bleach bit would have done anything bad.

Comment: Try typing `startx` & see if the error messages are helpful.

Comment: Not about your problem but about updating: Run `update` first (gets new list of available packages), then `dist-upgrade` (installs available software updates and does the same plus a little bit more as `upgrade`). Then you can run `autoremove`, `autoclean`, `clean` and `check` if you want, but they are not that important that they have to be run every day. If you follow this order (update, (dist-)upgrade, [if you want: autoremove, autoclean, clean, check]), you don't have to launch that bunch twice.

Comment: Hi @MarkWilliams  Thank you.  I tried that but with no success.  It ran some stuff to fast for me to see and then just sat there as if a process was running.  So I hit CTRL-C to get out and it told me something like the process had been stopped.

Comment: Hi @ByteCommander  Thank you.  I will change the order of my updates.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

So I got a hold of the manufacturer of my machine, System76, and they figured it out for me.  Turned out it was a bad .config file in my home directory.  So we renamed the `.config` directory `.config.bak`.

Reboot the machine and I'm good.  I had to rework some of my configurations for the launch bar and such, but I got my system back and in my own account.

All is well.  Thanks System 76!